# How to create a CDATA node in HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, cdata, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have been given the task of publishing our existing documentation to a Confluence wiki. I'm using node.js and jQuery to convert the html output from our doc tool to the Confluence format, and everything is going well, except when I try to display code. The problem has to do with CDATA. Confluence says this is how to create a code block:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="code">
  <ac:plain-text-body>
    <![CDATA[Code to be displayed goes here.]]>
  </ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

None of my attempts to create a CDATA node have worked, and I can't seem to find any doc anywhere on how to create a CDATA node in this context. Using jQuery's `.html()` makes the CDATA node into a comment, and `.text()` escapes the entities. Of course, this is exactly what the jQuery doc says they will do. So I'm stuck.

Maybe CDATA and jQuery just don't work this way? Admittedly I haven't studied CDATA much--it didn't occur to me that it would be an object of much study.

Am I totally doing this wrong? Is there a more "best practices" way of doing it?

Comment: This [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createCDATASection) does not work for you?

Comment: No, I tried that already, but that particular page tells me something I didn't know: _HTML documents do not support CDATA sections_. Ugh. Thanks.

Comment: I am using `<pre>` for code on [WIKI](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting)

Comment: Confluence wiki is proprietary, not a real wiki like wikimedia.